# PHP CLI hidden passwd input in Win7 using batch

Tags: php, batch-file, windows-7, command-line-interface

I am currently writing a PHP library (mainly for myself) which at some point will have the user enter a password and ofc I want it to be hidden (I go with pretty much anything as long as the password is not shown in full on screen). I have searched everywhere but all answers either doesn't work in Win7 or requires an external executable.

As it is supposed to be a library I want to keep it contained, so I have done some improvising and got so close that I am not willing to just fall back to an external .exe without putting up a question on SO.

My workaround bases on writing a temp batch file (which can be deleted afterwards or just use `tmpfile()`) and calling it using `exec()`:

```
@echo off
choice /c abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 /n /cs
echo %errorlevel%
```

Assuming the password is purely alphanumerical, I can determine the pressed key by the return value of `exec()`. Then I can just set up a loop to capture every keystroke. The only problem that remains, is that there is no way for the user to break off from `choice` as the enter key itself cannot be set up as one of the choices.

Any help or other workarounds are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this post by Carlos from DosTips.com

http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=26800#p26800